# What happened to the head-shot version?

Tags: triangle

We follow one iteration of Jess around the film, from the "first" time she steps on the ocean liner to the point where she "leaves".

She sees a lot of duplicates, one of which she manages to shoot in the head (not killing her, just grazing her fore head) and you can see a bit of blood coming out of her head, staining the hood.

We never see this line of events from the pivotal view of the version of Jess we are following from the beginning of the film. We only witness it as a foreshadow, right? Is this an error in the script? Can it be explained in-universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each version of Jess is essentially a different version of her. It's not a time loop. She is actually doing her best to change the outcome of events. We are following one version of Jess maybe the best version there is. The ones that came before may have been more violent or may have remembered a little more about what happens next and were lashing out. But over all each Jess will play out just a little bit differently than the others. It's her hell.

Comment: This raises the question how many Jess's there are. I'd think there is exactly one, because at the end of the film, everything starts anew. We can see that the main events repeat themselves more often than the number of Jess's that are on the ocean liner at a given time (wich I would say are a hand full). The number of corpses of the wife, serves as a counter, and there are a lot more corpses than a hand full.

Comment: I believe there are normally three Jess's on the boat at once. But how many overall loops have happened is only countable by the pile of dead women and the pile of dead seagulls. However I don't think that every Jess makes it off the boat alive.  So who knows how many cycles it is after all it is hell so it's going on for eternity.

Comment: If she didn't make it off the boat alive, at least on of the loops would probably be broken, wouldn't it? However, I agree that there are 2-3 Jess's on the boat at any given time. I think, I will have to watch the film again a couple of times, until I get my head around everything :)

Comment: Here is someone that came to the same conclusion as me and posted as a review for this movie. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1187064/board/nest/186465725

Comment: Well, the problem is that the loops are larger and more interleaved. She does try to change things, and for a couple iterations they do, but from the fact that a bunch of dead Sallies are on the upper deck, we can tell that there have been several iterations with the "head-shot" Jess, always alternating (some Sallies are shot in the theatre, some die upstairs). Another way to depict the Sisyphus theme.